# FileIO - Exception in thread "main" NullPointerException

Tags: java, file-io, io, nullpointerexception

When I run the main method, the following kept popping up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have checked my code, but unable to find any uninitialized variable. Can somebody please help me?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FileIO 
{
public static ArrayList<Person> readData(String fileName)
{
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    int index = -1;
    try
    {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        String s;
        Person p = null;
        boolean addressActive = false;
        while (reader.hasNext())
        {
            s = reader.nextLine();
            Scanner line = new Scanner(s);
            String cmd;

            if(line.hasNext())
            {
                cmd = line.next();

                if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
                {
                    index++;
                    p = new Person();
                    p.setName(line.nextLine());
                    personList.add(index,p);
                    addressActive = false;
                }

                else if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("birthday"))
                {
                    if(line.hasNext())
                    {
                        p.setBirthday(line.nextLine());
                        personList.set(index, p);
                    }
                    addressActive = false;

                }

                else if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("phone"))
                {
                    if(line.hasNext())
                    {
                        p.setPhone(line.nextLine());
                        personList.set(index, p);
                    }
                    addressActive = false;
                }

                else if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("email"))
                {
                    if(line.hasNext())
                    {
                        p.setEmail(line.nextLine());
                        personList.set(index, p);
                    }
                    addressActive = false;
                }

                else if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("address"))
                {
                    p.setAddress(line.nextLine());
                    personList.set(index, p);
                    addressActive = true;
                }

                else if(addressActive)
                {
                    String address = p.getAddress() + " " + s;
                    p.setAddress(address);
                    personList.set(index, p);
                }

                else
                    System.out.println("Error: no command" +s);
            }


        }
        reader.close(); 
        return personList;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        return null;
    }

}
}

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<Person> person1 = FileIO.readData("C:/Users/phoenix/Desktopsample_phonebook1.txt");


System.out.println(person1.size());

}
}
```

Seems i didnt do any changes, the problem just be fixed!! I really dont know why!!!!! It took me 3 hours to find the problem, but just in a second, it be fixed without letting me know what had happened.!
Anyway thank you for ur guys kindness help~~

Comment: An exception comes with a line number. Add e.printStackTrace() in your catch clause.

Comment: And depending on your file, p may very well be null.

Comment: Actually, you will get a stack trace by removing the line which hides it.  Take out your Try/catch block as you are better off not having it.

Comment: p may be null if the first command is not "name". The stack trace will tell for sure.

Comment: Please show us the whole error message. Not just `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`, but include all subsequent lines as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `p`. `Person p` is `null` at the start. You are creating an object of Person only when `cmd` is `name`. Apart from that you are trying to access a null reference, which leads to `NullPointerException` So, you mighw want to initialize `p` instead of makint it `null` at the start. You could do it here:

```
try
{
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
    String s;
    Person p = new Person();  // Initialize Person object
    boolean addressActive = false;
    while (reader.hasNext())
```

**EDIT :**

If you still can't get rid of the exception, use the printStacktrace method in catch block as follows:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @user2372861, Then you should use `e.printStacktrace();` in your catch block to find where exactly NPE is occuring.

Comment: how can i use e.printStacktrace()? i am a new learner..can u help?

Answer (score 1):

**Your null object**

The chances are, your file contains a token that is not equal to `name`. In which case, because `p` is only instantiated in the first `if block`, you will get a `NullPointerException` from that.

Ignoring the design flaws, I've noticed that `Person` has a no parameter constructor. In this case, there is no harm in moving that instantiation to the start.

```
Person p = new Person();

// Resume if else tree.
```

**Another potential issue**

In the same scenario, if you don't get "name" first, you will attempt to store a value at index `-1`, because of this instantiation:

```
int index = -1;
```

**How to use e.printStackTrace()**

In your `catch` clause, you have this:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error");
    return null;
}
```

Just simply replace the code with:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: int index = -1 means. when the program read the file, it reads "Name". index number will add 1 equal to 0 indicating the first index in the arraylist, then i create the new object

Comment: Does "name" always come first?

Answer (score 1):

You only create a person you a "name" is given.  If you run any other code first you will get a NPE.  It is quite likely what you code does depends on the input you give it. (Which is dangerous)